# How to respond to an md-slider while it is being dragged?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I've got a md-slider and a controller that correctly updates the volume when the drag event has finished; when the ng-model is changed.

This is the code in the controller that watches the volume property/attribute.

```
$scope.$watch(
        function () {
            return $scope.volume;
        },
        function (newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.changeVolumeViaNumberInput();
        }
);
```

This is the html that renders the slider.

```
<div>
    <label class="Body">Volume</label>
    <md-slider md-discrete aria-label="Volume" ng-model="volume" min="0" max="100">
    </md-slider>
</div>
```

What do I have to add to enable the controller to respond to the drag event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved by removing md-discrete.

```
<div>
    <label class="Body">Volume</label>
    <md-slider aria-label="Volume" ng-model="volume" min="0" max="100">
    </md-slider>
</div>
```